# VB Visual Studio doesn't update the bin/debug folder

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

A friend was working on a Visual Basic program in Visual Studio 2010 (Express) and all of a sudden, after the code is changed or the form is modified, Visual Studio refuses to update the program when we go to debug/build it.  It doesn't update the "MyAppName".exe at all.

I tried following the accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21470297/vb-net-code-not-executing-the-way-it-should-under-visual-studio) question, which suggests deleting all the content in the bin/debug/ folder, but when I try to build his program, it simply repopulates these files:

- MyAppName.vshost.exe.config
- MyAppName.exe.config
- MyAppName.vshost.exe

(I made sure I had closed VS prior to deleting, so that all the files were removed.)

If you press `F5` or the debug button, VS complains:

> Visual Studio cannot start debugging because the debug target 'C:\PATH_TO_PROJECT\bin\debug\MyAppName.exe' is missing...

and so on.

Any help?

Comment: Before deleting files did you try Build->Clean Solution, and then Build->Rebuild Solution?

Comment: Are you compiling the code in release mode?

Comment: @chaddienhart I did not try that... I did restore the deleted files, would it help to try that now? EDIT: Build->Clean Solution nor Build->Rebuild Solution are not available. I changedd his settings from basic to expert toolset, and now it builds! What's up?

Comment: @bastos.sergio Not as far as I know... I don't really use VB very often.  How would I check?

Comment: It happens often with VS 2010, in different flavours. Please share your setup, i.e. how many projects in a solution, and how they are relevant to each other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the steps in VS2010:

Step 1: Build -> Clean Solution
This will delete all the build output files

Step 2: Build -> Rebuild Solution
Rebuilds everything. 
Note: Build solution only builds the projects that Visual Studio determines need to be built (which is why you are not seeing all files updated). Visual Studio gets this wrong sometimes.

[image]

You can check to see if you are build configuration via Build -> Configuration Manager.

Comment: Thanks! This seems like it will fix it in the future too.

Comment: When I Clean the files aren't deleted, so the following steps doesn't work. I must to Close the IDE and delete the.files manually. Very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

In my case root of cause was bad one of the project, that was used in many other projects. I fixed it and resolve all issues.