# Visual Studio doesn't remove deleted files/folders from bin/debug folder

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I feel like this is a stupid question, but I googled to no avail, so I'm going to ask anyway. In my Visual Studio project, I created a folder "Test". I ran the project in debug mode and the code was built and added to the bin/debug folder as expected. Later I deleted the Test folder, but on the next debug I found that the previously deleted directory and files were still there. The presence of these old files is causing issues with debugging and I can certainly just go delete them, but I'm thinking it should handle this automagically. Am I wrong?

I tried running clean, build, rebuild as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250578/vb-visual-studio-doesnt-update-the-bin-debug-folder), none of which removed these invalid files from the debug folder.

Comment: `I created a folder "Test"` Did you create/add it in VS, or does the program you wrote create those when running? VS is not going to delete (or restore) folders//files other than its own. You would need to add an [`AfterClean`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-extend-the-visual-studio-build-process?view=vs-2019) target for that.

Comment: I created it using right click Add -> New Folder. I will look into AfterClean.